# how to set font in html for iphone application

Tags: html, iphone, fonts

I am setting font in html but it is not working.  here is the my code.

```
    NSString * emailBody =@"<html><body>Thank you for your participation in
    Consulting<br>Practitioner and Client Program.</br>
    <br>Attached is the copy of your signed contract for your records
    <p>Please email or fax your completed W-9 form to
    <br>our PEI Support Team
    <br>Email:PEISupportServices@zoetis.com
    <br>Fax:800-741-1310
    <p><b><u><font color:'#888888'>IMPORTANT: Please provide invoice for this 
    consultation to your Zoetis Representative to ensure payment.  
    Do NOT mail directly to Zoetis.</u></b>
    <p>Billing Address:<br>Zoetis<br>100 Campus Drive<br>Florham Park, NJ  07932
    <body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your HTML is invalid. Specifically for your font you need

```
<font color="#888888">
```

You're mixing CSS syntax with HTML syntax. You also have no closing `</font>` tag anywhere.

Also your body tag is opened at the end. You need `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

I used in following ways, font name and colour

```
     - (NSString *)messageBody
     {


             NSMutableString *emailBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div> \n"
                                  "<p style=\"font:17px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\">%@</p> \n"
                                  "<h1 style=\"font:bold 16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"%@\">%@</a></h1> \n"
                                  "<br> \n"
                                  "<table align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<tbody> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969;font-weight:bold\"> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td align=\"left\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969\"> \n"
                                  "Please note that you have not been added to any email lists. \n"
                                  "</span> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "</tbody> \n"
                                  "</table> \n"
                                  "</div>",
                                  self.message,
                                  [self.appStoreURL absoluteString],
                                  self.applicationName
                                  ];

             return emailBody;

         }
```